# Checking $U^{\dagger} U=I$ for Lorentz boost

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, inertial-frames, unitarity

The boost is given by $|p\rangle \rightarrow |\Lambda p\rangle$. I can understand that this is unitary because the inner product :

$$\int dp \frac{1}{2\omega _p} f(p) g^*(p) ....(1)$$

is invariant. I'd also like to check unitarity using $U^{\dagger} U=I$.

$U$ can be represented as :

$$f(p')=U[f(p)]=\int dp \delta (\Lambda p - p') f(p) $$

Is this correct? This is designed to ensure that $f(p')=f(\Lambda p)$

Then, I took the above representation of $U$ to compute $U^{\dagger} U$

$$=\int dp' \delta (\Lambda p_1 - p')\delta (\Lambda p_2 -p')$$

$$= \delta (\Lambda p_1 - \Lambda p_2)$$

This is not equal to Identity, which is $\delta (p_1 -p_2)$ .

**How to fix this analysis**?

According to the comment below, this is equal to identity. One problem is that i never had to use the definition of an inner product in $(1)$ to prove this. i only had to use $U[f(p)]=f(\Lambda p)$ This proof implies that the following inner product should be Lorentz invariant:

$$\int dp f(p) g^* (p)$$

$$=\int dp f(p) I g^* (p)$$

$$=\int dp f(p) UU^{\dagger} g^* (p)$$

$$=\int dp f(\Lambda p) g (\Lambda p)$$

which would be an incorrect conlusion

**How to avoid this conclusion while showing $U^{\dagger} U=I$ for boosts**?

Comment: $\delta ( \Lambda p_1 - \Lambda p_2 ) = \frac{\delta ( p_1 - p_2 )}{ | \det \Lambda |} 
 = \delta ( p_1 - p_2 ) $

Comment: @stringynonsense wow. How to prove this

Comment: It is a standard property of the Dirac delta function.

Comment: A quick google search yielded e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.02871.pdf); see proposition 2.3. As usual, it suffices (at least at the level of the average physicist) to pick a suitable representation of $\delta$ and prove the property, as done in the article.

Comment: Related : [Physical meaning of the Jacobian in relation to Dirac delta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371700/physical-meaning-of-the-jacobian-in-relation-to-dirac-delta-function/371706#371706).

Comment: Your conclusion is absolutely correct. Since $p$ is an integration variable, you can change $p \to \Lambda^{-1} p$ so we have $\int d ( \Lambda^{-1} p ) f(p) g^*(p)$. You then use the fact that $d ( \Lambda^{-1} p) = d p$ (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214674/why-is-d4p-obviously-lorentz-invariant/214675#214675)

Comment: @Prahar but the wavefunction as defined on momentum 3-space, so it is $d^3p$

Comment: You should be way more careful with your notation then. In that case, the measure in the last part should be $dp \frac{1}{2\omega_p}$ just like you had in your equation (1). Importantly, the measure $dp \frac{1}{2\omega_p}$ is Lorentz invariant (just like $d^4p$) so your conclusion is still correct!

Comment: @Prahar yes, it is supposed to be correct with the $\frac{1}{2\omega _p}$ included, but I am getting this conclusion even without it, by assuming the inner product is defined without the $\frac{1}{2\omega _p}$, and using $U^{\dagger} U=I$

Comment: @RyderRude - you are making a mistake. Why don't you redo the calculation being extra careful with all the factors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's write down all the right formulas. The inner product is
$$
(f,g) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_p} f^*(p) g(p) , \qquad \omega_p = \sqrt{ | \vec{p} |^2 + m^2 } . 
$$
The action of a unitary operator is
$$
\tag{1}
U_\Lambda f(p) = f(\Lambda p) = \int d^3 p' \delta^3( \Lambda p-p') f(p') .
$$
Using the definition of $U^\dagger$
\begin{align}
(U_\Lambda^\dagger f , g) &= ( f , U_\Lambda g) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_p} f^*(p) U_\Lambda g (p) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_p} f^*(p) g (\Lambda p) 
\end{align}
We now change the integration variable to $p \to \Lambda^{-1} p$. Using the fact that the integration measure is Lorentz invariant, we find
$$
(U_\Lambda^\dagger f , g) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_p} f^*(\Lambda^{-1} p) g (p) 
$$
Since this is true for any $g(p)$, we must have
$$
U_\Lambda^\dagger f(p) = f(\Lambda^{-1} p). 
$$
We can now check that the operator is unitary
$$
U_\Lambda^\dagger U_\Lambda f(p) = U_\Lambda^\dagger f(\Lambda p)  = f( \Lambda^{-1} \Lambda p ) = f(p) 
$$
so that $U_\Lambda^\dagger U_\Lambda = I$.

---

Alternatively, we can follow your way of deriving unitarity. The idea is that we must find the momentum representation of the operator $U_\Lambda(p,p')$. For this, we must be careful about the normalization of the inner product. Rewriting (1), we have
$$
U_\Lambda f(p) = \int \frac{d^3 p'}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_{p'}} [ (2\omega_{p'} )(2\pi)^3 \delta^3( \Lambda p-p') ] f(p') .
$$
Therefore,
$$
U_\Lambda(p,p') = (2\omega_{p'} )(2\pi)^3 \delta^3( \Lambda p-p') .
$$
Similarly,
$$
U^\dagger_\Lambda(p,p') = (2\omega_{p'}) ( 2\pi)^3 \delta^3( \Lambda^{-1} p - p') = (2\omega_p) ( 2\pi)^3 \delta^3( p - \Lambda p') 
$$
where in the last equality, we used the fact that the Dirac delta function is Lorentz invariant, i.e.
$$
(2\omega_{\Lambda p}) \delta^3 ( \Lambda p - \Lambda p' ) = (2\omega_p) \delta^3( p - p') 
$$
We can now check unitarity,
\begin{align}
U_\Lambda^\dagger U_\Lambda (p,p') &= \int \frac{d^3p''}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_{p''}} U_\Lambda^\dagger(p,p'') U_\Lambda (p'',p') \\
&= \int \frac{d^3p''}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2\omega_{p''}} [ (2\omega_{p''} )(2\pi)^3 \delta^3( \Lambda p-p'') ] [ (2\omega_{p''}) ( 2\pi)^3 \delta^3( p'' - \Lambda p') ] \\
&= (2\omega_{\Lambda p}) ( 2\pi)^3 \delta^3( \Lambda p - \Lambda p')  \\
&= (2\omega_p) ( 2\pi)^3 \delta^3( p - p') \\
&= I(p,p') . 
\end{align}
The last object is the identity operator in the momentum representation.

Comment: hi. i've also written an answer which may give another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the last part of your expression you have
$$\intop dpf\left(\Lambda p\right)g\left(\Lambda p\right)=\intop\det\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)dp'f\left(p'\right)g\left(p'\right)=\intop dp'f\left(p'\right)g\left(p'\right)$$
Which is just a coordinate transformation with nothing special about. I think the confusion rises from the fact that the state is not described by a 4-vector but a 3-momentum vector when you canonically quantize it. You have $\left|\overrightarrow{p}\right\rangle =a_{\overrightarrow{p}}^{\dagger}\left|0\right\rangle$, we define $\left\langle 0|0\right\rangle =1$ and we have
$$\left\langle 0\right|a_{\overrightarrow{q}}a_{\overrightarrow{p}}^{\dagger}\left|0\right\rangle =\left\langle 0\right|\left[a_{\overrightarrow{q}},a_{\overrightarrow{p}}^{\dagger}\right]\left|0\right\rangle =\left(2\pi\right)^{3}\delta^{\left(3\right)}\left(\overrightarrow{p}-\overrightarrow{q}\right)$$
This delta function is not Lorentz invariant but $E_{\overrightarrow{p}}\delta^{\left(3\right)}\left(\overrightarrow{p}-\overrightarrow{q}\right)$ is! You can check it by taking a Lorentz transformation in some direction (breaking the delta function into $\delta\left(p_{\parallel}-q_{\parallel}\right)\delta^{\left(2\right)}\left(p_{\perp}-q_{\perp}\right)$) and it will result in
$$E'_{\overrightarrow{p}}\delta^{\left(3\right)}\left(\overrightarrow{p}'-\overrightarrow{q}'\right)=E_{\overrightarrow{p}}\delta^{\left(3\right)}\left(\overrightarrow{p}-\overrightarrow{q}\right)$$
That's why you're going to see it next to the delta function a lot during quantization and the results will be Lorentz invariant.

Comment: For relativistic models, we can define $|\vec p\rangle \equiv \sqrt{2E_{\vec p}}a^\dagger_{\vec p}|0\rangle$, so that $\langle \vec q|\vec p\rangle = 2E_{\vec p}(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec p - \vec q)$ is Lorentz invariant. (See Peskin and Schoroder at Chapter 2.)

Comment: Also, in your second block formula section, you have introduced a factor of $(2\pi)^3$ for no reason in going from the first LHS to the first RHS. The $(2\pi)^3$ comes from the canonical commutation relation: $[a_{\vec p}, a^\dagger_{\vec q}]=(2\pi)^3\delta(\vec p - \vec q)$...

Comment: You can define it both ways. My teacher did it that way. The computations turn out the same either way when you're looking for observables. You're right about the factors, it was a typo, Thanks.
I wouldn't recommend anyone to read/follow Peskin and Schoroder.

Comment: What book would you recommend?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no perfect book on the matter (that I'm aware of). I have read Peskin and for me it felt more like a handbook than teaching book, it can be good if you want to get a formula you've forgotten because after errata there are little mistakes left.
But to study I would recommend the second edition of A. Zee QFT in a nutshell as a main source with intuition and motivation and supplementing it with other books that do other parts pretty well, e.g. Ryder has a good explanation of the LSZ reduction and Srednicki was also good for specific problems as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

The analysis in the latter half of the post is completely incorrect. It arises by using a mix of integral and matrix notation.

Let's just stick to one notation at a time. The inner product is given by :

$$\int d^3p \frac{1}{2\omega _p} f(p) g^*(p)$$

In Einstein notation, this may be re-written as:

$$f_p M^{pp'} g^* _{p'}$$

where $M^{pp'}=\frac{1}{2\omega _p}\delta (p-p')$. Repeated indices are integrated over.

If $U^a_b$ is a transformation, then the transformed inner product is:

$$f_a U^a _b M^{bc} U^{*d}_c g^* _d$$

We can see that the inner product is invariant iff :

$$U^a_b M^{bc} U^{*d}_c= M^{ad}$$

The above is the condition of unitarity. We can see that it explicitly involves the inner product measure encoded in $M$. So when a transformation matrix satisfies this condition, the inner product with the specific measure given by $M$ is invariant.

Here, $*$ represents a complex conjugate rather than the adjoint.

Comment: The latter half of which answer? Mine? All calculations in my answer are most definitely correct. You are likely misunderstanding something (which I would certainly consider my failure), but there is nothing incorrect in the answer itself.

Comment: @Prahar no, i mean the latter half of my post where i concluded that that other inner product was invariant too

Comment: @Prahar sorry. ive edited it to say "post".

Comment: yep! got it! sorry for the confusion.